# loop a youtube video in iframe

Tags: video, iframe, youtube

I am trying to build a website where i want to use a youtube video as a background, the video automatically starts as intended but it won't loop itself no matter what i try.

also, I need to mute the video's audio on command but i can't seem to get that working either.

```
<iframe width="320" height="240"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1dbVv7heh0?&autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=w1dbVv7heh0E" frameborder='0'>
</iframe>
```

if anyone could help me out i would be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

```js
https://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?
    version=3
    &loop=1
    &playlist=VIDEO_ID
```

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#loop

Comment: don't forget the `playlist` attribute like I did...  It only works if that's included, even though it's completely useless

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the playlist parameter along with the loop. For playlist, set it's value as the current video id.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item"id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=M7lc1UVf-VE"
      frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Note: In your case playlist="videoId" is not matching with current video id.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a direct mp4 file to replace youtube iframe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a `&` directly after the link `https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1dbVv7heh0?`.

Correct code:

```
<iframe width="320" height="240"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w1dbVv7heh0?autoplay=1&loop=1&showinfo=0&color=white&iv_load_policy=3&playlist=w1dbVv7heh0E" frameborder='0'>
</iframe>
```

Also, Youtube doesn't allow some videos to play on localhosts. So, you have to buy a domain and run your website on it.